# XPath selector for element with specified attribute value and has descendant with specified attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm looking for an XPath selector which will get an element with a specified attribute value and also a descendant with a specified attribute value. The following is an example:

```
<book type="nonfiction">
    <title>foo</title>
    <author>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <dob>1/1/1900</dob>
    </author>
</book>
<book type="fiction">
    <title>bar</title>
    <author>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
        <dob>2/2/2000</dob>
    </author>
</book>
```

So in this example I'd like to get all the `<book>` elements with a `type` of nonfiction who have an `<author>` with a `dob` of 1/1/1900. I don't know how many levels deep the `<author>` node is though so I need a solution that can check all descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
//book[@type='nonfiction' and .//author[dob='1/1/1900']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to get the desired output:

```
//book[@type = "nonfiction"][.//author[dob = "1/1/1900"]]
```